# PHP and MYSQL inserting information into a database, not working.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
  $sent = $_GET['sent'];

  if($sent == "yes") {

      require('database_connection.php');
      $name = $_GET['name'];
      $desc = $_GET['desc'];
      $email = $_SESSION['Memberid'];

      date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
      $date = date("d.m.y"); 



      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$email.'` (`id`, `Note`, `Share Url`, `Name`, `Description`, `Date`, `Type`) VALUES (\'\', \'Enter Note Here.\',  \'\',  \''.$name.'\', \''.$desc.'\', \''.$date.'\', \'Text\')';
      $i = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

        if($i) {
            echo '<h2>Created note.</h2>';
            header( 'Location: https://daccaa.com/edits' ) ;
        } else {
            echo '<h2>Failed to create a note for you.</h2>';
            echo $name.'<br />';
            echo $desc.'<br />';
            echo $email.'<br />';
            echo $date.'<br />';
            echo $sql.'<br />';
            echo $i.'<br />';
            echo '<h1 style="visibility: hidden;">_</h1>';
            echo '<a href="https://daccaa.com/contact" class="new">Let us Know.</a>';
        }

  } else {
      echo '<div class="holder">
    <h1>Lets create a new note:</h1>
    <h3 style="visibility: hidden;">_</h3>
        <form method="GET" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="myBox" placeholder="Enter Name Here" />
            <input type="text" name="desc" class="myBox" placeholder="Enter Description Here" /> <br />
            <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="sent" />
            <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="select" /><br />
            <a href="https://daccaa.com/edits/" class="select">Go Back</a> 
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>';
  }

  ?>
```

The code above is from my website, the idea behind the code is that it will create a new row in the database with the information upon its execution.

This is what the testing upon failure will echo:

```
new_test_name
new_test_desc
49
02.07.14
INSERT INTO `49` (`id`, `Note`, `Share Url`, `Name`, `Description`, `Date`, `Type`) VALUES ('', 'Enter Note Here.', '', 'new_test_name', 'new_test_desc', '02.07.14', 'Text')
```

But I still cannot seem to get the value to enter, This similar method works fine on another page, I can pretty much eliminate the fact that it could be in the database file as it works fine on another page in the same directory.

The structure of the MYSQL database is:

id | Note | Share Url | Name | Description | Date | Type

Please note I will be going over this later to add more ways to prevent SQL injection, I just want to get the basic code sorted out first.

Comment: If you use `mysqli_error()` it would tell you what your error is.

Comment: Is your ID is not set as autoincrement? If so, you shouldn't use it in insert query

Comment: Is `49` really the name of your table?

Comment: 'INSERT INTO `'.$email.'` Seems to be suspicious to me, did you mean table name?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have removed the ID as it is set to auto increment but it still will not work.

Comment: You absolutely need to escape those GET paramerters!. Even better would it be to use a library like PDO and paramterize the query to avoid injections.

Comment: Did you name your table '49'?  Because that's where you're trying to insert to.

Comment: @DownMasters.com The email part uses the member ID, What would I need to do to take on board your suggestion?

Comment: @durbnpoisn The table name is 49

Comment: Your query is quite strange: `INSERT INTO $email (id, Note, Share Url, Name, Description, Date, Type) VALUES ('', 'Enter Note Here.',  '',  '$name', '$desc', '$date', 'Text')';` (I improved readability.) You are passing an empty string in as `id`, but you should just drop the `id` field from the list of column names and not specify a value at all.

Comment: You should check if you don't have any unique keys

Comment: But this entire comment thread remains speculation until you get us the `mysql_error()`.

Comment: `mysqli` supports parametrized queries. Why don't you use `prepare` and `bind_param`?

Comment: @11684 How would I use the `mysql_error()`?

Comment: While MySQLi is a fine library, if you are going to switch libraries anyway, I recommend PDO. It supports named parameters (which is quite valuable in long queries with lots of parameters), while MySQLi does not.

Comment: @DannyFranklin If the return value of `mysql_query()` evaluates to false, just `echo` `mysql_error()`.

Comment: I did forget to mention that I am fairly new to MySQL.

Comment: @11684.  He is using mysqli, not mysql.

Comment: @DannyFranklin, it seems you need to read up on some tutorials.  Google how to debug mysqli queries and how to prevent SQL injections with mysqli.

Comment: @11684 With the changes this is what I got:

Comment: @11684 `INSERT INTO `49` ( `Note`, `Share Url`, `Name`, `Description`, `Date`, `Type`) VALUES ( 'Enter Note Here.', '', 'asd', 'asda', '02.07.14', 'Text')

Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: @Devon Thank you for the suggestions, that is something I will do. I can normally manage to sort out some of the smaller problems but this one has got me.

Comment: @Devon Apparently, I just read over the i. Still, PDO does support named parameters.

Comment: @DannyFranklin It seems I was right. Try this: $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$email.'` (`Note`, `Share Url`, `Name`, `Description`, `Date`, `Type`) VALUES (\'Enter Note Here.\',  \'\',  \''.$name.'\', \''.$desc.'\', \''.$date.'\', \'Text\')';

Comment: It seems SO recognised the backticks as formatting delimiters. Don't know what I can do about that. I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message: `Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

I'm assuming id is your primary key.  Make sure you have auto increment setup on this column and then just exclude the id field completely in the query.

Right now your inserting a blank ID.  Without strict enforcement, MySQL will convert an empty value to a 0 for an integer field.  So you are trying to insert into ID 0 every time rather than creating a new row.

**Dangers of your query**

You are using unsanitized user input in your query (GET).  GET, POST, REQUEST, and COOKIE variables should always be used with prepared queries.

Right now I could load your url with something like `?name="'; DELETE FROM 49 WHERE 1;"` and wipe out your entire table.  Research SQL injections and how to use MySQLi to make prepared queries.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. It works fine now. Once again thank you all.

Comment: @DannyFranklin read my additions on the dangers of this query.